# How to avoid starving BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, bufferedinputstream

I read data from a source location via `BufferedInputStream` and I pass the data to a destination using `BufferedOutputStream`. The problem I'm having is that sometimes my thread never exits the while loop because of starving on the bandwidth. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sourceConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedOutputStream request = new BufferedOutputStream(destConnection.getOutputStream());
request.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
boolean eof = false;
byte[] input = new byte[4096];
while ((length = bis.read(input)) != -1) {
    request.write(input, 0, length);
    request.flush();
}
request.close();
bis.close();
```

Comment: Your question seems a little off; the thread will *never* exit the loop if the connections stays open. Why should it?

Comment: If the issue is that your output stream isnt flushing, just move the flush() call in the loop after you write the bytes to it. As it stands, I agree with Durandal. That loop should only exit in the event of disconnect, or some other equally unrecoverable event.

Comment: The code I changed still doesn't work. Look at the edit.

Comment: Your `while` loop could be shrinked to this: `while ((length = bis.read(input)) != -1) { request.write(input, 0, length); request.flush(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix the issue I did a few things. I set the entire transfer process in a separate thread using an executor with a timeout

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Future<Boolean> handler = executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return processTransfer();
    }
});
success = handler.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

That way if the transfer takes longer than 10 minutes, it exits with an exeption. The second thing was change the original code to detect starvation:

```
long lastDataRecvTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
byte[] input;
while (true) {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDataRecvTime >= 5 * 60 * 1000) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Nothing received for 5 minutes. Transfer starved. Exiting");
    }
    int availableBuf = request.getAvailableBufferSize();
    if(availableBuf == 0) {
        request.flush();
        continue;
    }
    input = new byte[Math.min(4096, availableBuf)];
    int length = bis.read(input);
    if (length == -1)
        break;

    if(length == 0) {
        try { Thread.sleep(1); } catch (Exception ignored){}
        continue;
    }

    lastDataRecvTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    request.write(input, 0, length);
}
request.flush();
request.close();
bis.close();
```

Thanks for the help